# Age Verify code kicking people out of to old?

Tags: php, if-statement, verify

my code is letting people in if there above 19 but also if your to old its not letting you enter why is this ? I had a person try to enter my site today with 1958 and got kicked out yet i can enter 1989 and it works fine

index page

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>510 Vapour</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<div class="js">
<body>
  <!-- Preloader section -->
<div id="preloader"></div>
 <!-- Preloader section -->
<div class="container"> 
  <!-- AccessBox section -->
  <div id="accessbox"class="animated bounceInDown"> <img class="profile-img" src="images/logo.png" />
    <h2 class="text-center">Please enter your date of birth</h2>
    <!-- Form section-->
    <form action="php/access.php" method="post" class="access-form">
      <input type="text" name="yy" class="access-input-lg" placeholder="2016" required autofocus>
      <input type="text" name="mm" class="access-input" placeholder="05">
      <input type="text" name="dd" class="access-input" placeholder="10">
      <input type="submit" name="submit"class="access-btn" value="OK" >
      <div id="remember" class="checkbox text-center">
        <label class="text-center">
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">
          Remember me </label>
      </div>
    </form>
    <!-- Form section-->
    <h1 class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle red"></i> You must be 19+ to enter this site </h1>
    <p class="text-center">By ENTERING, you are consenting to your Province's Smoking Laws. You may be required to show a valid government issued Photo ID indicating your date of birth at time of delivery or at the Post Office.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- AccessBox section --> 
</div>
<!-- /container --> 
<!-- JS files--> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Pre Loader--> 
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  

$(window).load(function(){
    $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();});
});

});
</script>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

access.php

```
<?php

    $minAge = 19;

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        if(strlen($_POST['mm'])==1)
        $month = '0'.$_POST['mm'];
        else 
        $month = $_POST['mm'];
        $agevar = $_POST['yy'];

      $age = strtotime($agevar);

      $nineteen = strtotime("-" . $minAge . " years");

      if($age && $nineteen && $age <= $nineteen){

         header('Location: https://www.510vapour.com/main');

      }

      else{

        header('Location: ../error.html');

      }

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Use curly braces for *all* control blocks and you will have a lot less bugs like this. Also , don't use strtotime for date math. It is not intended for that.

Comment: Why don't you check the day ? the user may have born on the last day of the month and technically he's still 18 yo.

Comment: lol sorry im new to php so i semi dont get what your saying can you help please

Comment: year input placeholder shows  4 digits (2016) but your post is getting only 2 `$agevar = $_POST['yy'];`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easier solution :

```
if (time() < strtotime('+19 years', strtotime($dob))) {
   //User is under 19 years of age
   header('Location: ../error.html');
}else{
   header('Location: https://www.510vapour.com/main');
}
```

Valid `$dob`

`1979-02-21` or `21 Feb 1986`

---

You can also use a [jQuery script](https://rawgit.com/fearlessflyer/age-check/master/index.html) to check user's age.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime` objects to calculate the person's exact age and select the appropriate action based on that.

Using `year-month-day` format when constructing the object should work regardless of the number of digits provided for year, month or day.

```
$birthdate = new DateTime($_POST['yy'].'-'.$_POST['mm'].'-'.$_POST['dd']);
$now = new DateTime;
$age = $birthdate->diff($now);

if ($age->y >= $minAge){
    header('Location: https://www.510vapour.com/main');
} else {
    header('Location: ../error.html');
}
```

Comment: sorry im new to php so where would that piece of code go ?

Comment: This could replace everything inside the `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` block.

Comment: This is a minimal example, however. You would still need to do things like making sure the necessary `$_POST` variables are actually set to valid values and handling errors if they aren't.

Comment: <?php

 $minAge = 19;
 
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  
  $birthdate = new DateTime($_POST['yy'].'-'.$_POST['mm'].'-'.$_POST['dd']);
  $now = new DateTime;
  $age = $birthdate->diff($now);

  if ($age->y >= $minAge){
   header('Location: https://www.510vapour.com/main');
  } else {
   header('Location: ../error.html');
  }

 }

 ?>

Comment: i did that and got an error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (1989--) at position 4 (-): Unexpected character' in /home/cvrxldmw/public_html/php/access.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /home/cvrxldmw/public_html/php/access.php(7): DateTime->__construct('1989--') #1 {main} thrown in /home/cvrxldmw/public_html/php/access.php on line 7

Comment: That error looks like `$_POST['mm']` and `$_POST['dd']` were empty, and the code in my answer depends on them being set to valid values. As I mentioned in my previous comment, you'll need to make sure they at least contain numbers before using the code in my answer.